# How to shutdown computer from a .NET Core application running on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, daemon

I have a .net core 2.0 program running on Linux (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS).

I'm trying to shutdown the computer by invoking a process with the following command: `sudo shutdown -h now`, though when the program is running in the background as daemon service, the shutdown process does not work.

Here is the code:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SHELL"),
        Arguments = "-s"
    },
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

if (process.Start())
{
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("sudo shutdown -h now");
}
```

My assumption is that the service runs as a separate session so it doesn't have any control. How can I get the application to shutdown the computer when it is running as a Linux daemon?

Comment: When running as a deamon your process probably lacks privileges to call `sudo` - or `sudo` starts but it immediately prompts for a password, so it sits idle.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend changing your code to use P/Invoke to call Linux's `reboot` function directly, this will also give you more details if it fails.

While invoking other executables to perform tasks is the convention on Unix/Linux (especially from shell scripts), .NET programs really don't fit in well and the code required is very brittle (e.g. as you're seeing with `sudo`), especially as in the .NET world processing Standard IO (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`) from other processes is very difficult.

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport( "libc.so", SetLastError = true)] // You may need to change this to "libc.so.6" or "libc.so.7" depending on your platform)
    public static extern Int32 reboot(Int32 magic, Int32 magic2, Int32 cmd, IntPtr arg);

    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1 = unchecked((int)0xfee1dead);
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2 = 672274793;
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2A = 85072278;
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2B = 369367448;
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2C = 537993216;


    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART = 0x01234567;
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_HALT = unchecked((int)0xCDEF0123);
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_CAD_ON = unchecked((int)0x89ABCDEF);
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_CAD_OFF = 0x00000000;
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF = 0x4321FEDC;
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART2 = unchecked((int)0xA1B2C3D4);
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_SW_SUSPEND = unchecked((int)0xD000FCE2);
    public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_KEXEC = 0x45584543;

    public const Int32 EPERM  =  1;
    public const Int32 EFAULT = 14;
    public const Int32 EINVAL = 22;
}
```

Usage:

```
using static NativeMethods;

public static void Shutdown()
{
    Int32 ret = reboot( LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, IntPtr.Zero );

    // `reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF)` never returns if it's successful, so if it returns 0 then that's weird, we should treat it as an error condition instead of success:
    if( ret == 0 ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF) returned 0.");

    // ..otherwise we expect it to return -1 in the event of failure, so any other value is exceptional:
    if( ret != -1 ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Unexpected reboot() return value: " + ret );

    // At this point, ret == -1, which means check `errno`!
    // `errno` is accessed via Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), even on non-Win32 platforms and especially even on Linux

    Int32 errno = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    switch( errno )
    {
    case EPERM:
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException( "You do not have permission to call reboot()" );

    case EINVAL:
        throw new ArgumentException( "Bad magic numbers (stray cosmic-ray?)" );

    case EFAULT:
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "Could not call reboot():" + errno.ToString() );
    }
}
```

Note that a successful call to `reboot()` will never return.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to implement it in this way but got the error as -1 from reboot(). Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @IX92 My apologies. I misread the documentation. I've updated my answer. If it returns `-1` then you get the error number via `errno` (`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` - even on Linux). The error-number is _not_ the return value.

Comment: It appears several of the values may need to be marked `unchecked` since they can't be held by a signed integer in C#. For example, `public const int LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_CAD_ON = unchecked((int)0x89ABCDEF)`.

Comment: @TravisIllig The C# compiler defaults to `unchecked`. Does your project have checked arithmetic enabled by default?

Comment: This potentially could be something that changed. `dotnet new console` to get a new console app, then add `public const Int32 LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1 = 0xfee1dead;` to `Program.cs` yields the compile error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @Dai  got always `EINVAL` (Bad magic numbers) as error code. Using libc.so.6 on an ARM processor.

Comment: I was getting the same as @MaxR. Using strace, I could see something strange was going on: `reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, 0xfee1dead /* LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)` - It appears the first two magic numbers are not required for this invocation method.
Changing the DllImport to `public static extern Int32 reboot(Int32 cmd, IntPtr arg);` and invoking via `reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, IntPtr.Zero);` works fine.

Comment: When I run dotnet run <MyProg> I get unauthorized. When I run sudo dotnet run <MyProg> it says dotnet is not installed

Answer (score 2):

Adding that, for .net core running on the Raspberry Pi, we need to use the other answer, but follow user Tom's comment and change the DllImport to:

```
[DllImport( "libc.so.6", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Int32 reboot(Int32 cmd, IntPtr arg);
```

And then to power off we can call:

```
reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Or to reboot:

```
reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu Server, used in daemon. Tested only there, may work also elsewhere.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/bin/sudo";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/sbin/shutdown -h now";
process.Start();
```